# Are there any subsets $A, B$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $\sup(B)>\sup(A)$ but none of the elements of $B$ are upperbounds of $A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If not, then how would you prove it? I've thought of multiple examples that do not support this but cannot think of how to go about proving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $b:=\sup B>\sup A=:a $. Then for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have $B\cap(b-\varepsilon,b]\neq\varnothing$. Since $b>a$ we can choose $\varepsilon$ such that $b-\varepsilon>a$, and thus $B$ has an element greather than $a$, and this is an upper bound for $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Now I need the fact that $\sup(A),\sup(B)\in \mathbb{R}$ by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$.

Then since $\sup{A}<\sup{B}$, so $\exists b^*\in B$ such that $b^*>\sup{A}$ (by definition of sup).

Hence, $b^*$ is the desired upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption:   $\forall b\in B \exists a\in A : a\gt b$.

But, $\forall a\in A, a\le supA$, by definition.

So $\forall b\in B, supA\ge b$.

Thus $supA\ge supB$...

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, try thinking about the definitions. Here's how you do that.

$\sup B\gt\sup A$

$\sup B$ is the **LEAST UPPER BOUND** of $B.$

Sinse $\sup B$ is the **LEAST** upper bound of $B,$ **nothing smaller than $\sup B$ can be an upper bound of $B.$**

Since $\sup A$ is smaller than $\sup B,$ that means **$\sup A$ is not an upper bound of $B.$**

Since $\sup A$ is not an upper bound of $B,$ that means **some element of $B$ is bigger than $\sup A.$**

Since $\sup A$ is an upper bound of $A,$ that means **some element of $B$ is bigger than an upper bound of $A.$**

Since anything bigger than an upper bound is also an upper bound, that means **some element of $B$ is an upper bound of $A.$**